# USB powered Desk Fan vs AC powered Desk Fan

Tags: usb, 12v

I would like to convince my employer, a government agency that relies exclusively on battery operated desktop fans, to convert to USB powered desktop fans plugged into employee desktop computers. Employees are restricted from using AC powered fans. All 75 users have desktop computers with 4 USB ports. 
How can I calculate how much additional current a 12 volt USB desk fan would add to the load of the desktop computer? Am I correct in assuming that a USB powered desktop fan would be the most energy efficient solution to the problem of 75 users needing desktop fans? Thank you all for your input!

Comment: Why is it necessary to do all that? A government agency should be ok with just getting what needs to be purchased surely?

Comment: @MCG: A nice idea, sure, but there are lists of approved vendors.

Comment: Thanks for replying. We are the County and have a limit on how much power we use in our "old" building. Now that Computers are more energy efficient than when the policy was written, the limit is probably moot but I have been hired as a new buyer and I can't believe the volume of batteries that are being consumed. I am hoping for some smart tips to justify USB devices. I am not an EE but a high end Computer User and would like to make the case for USB devices. They seem more practical.

Comment: So the real question is, is a 12V USB device drawing current from a new desktop computer more energy efficient than the same device drawing power from AC or from a similar model drawing power from 4 D batteries (that get changed ever few months). Thanks all for your thoughts!

Comment: If it's USB it'll be 5V. Just check the specs and see their power ratings

Comment: Vet any source carefully. A nefarious USB chip could lead to a data leakage, something a govt office at any level wouldn't want. And if it happens you may be the fall guy for asking for them in the first place.

Comment: I like the idea of reducing the use of single-use batteries.  Good luck, and thanks for trying!

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is NO.

First, there is no 12 V USB, at least in the normal desktop PC. The 5-V little toy fans are just toys.

Second, to get the USB port power, personal computers use AC-DC power supplies, ATX12V style or similar. They usually operate at 30% of max load, and efficiency is about 80% in that mode. So the conversion into USB power is only 80% efficient as compared to wall outlet.

Third, if you plan to convert 5V USB into 12-V fans, there will be another 20% loss in efficiency, not counting that you will likely consume all USB power budget and occupy all USB ports (due to current limits of USB connectors).

So the USB idea is really not flying.

What you need to do is to get a $30 AC wattmeter (Kill-A-Watt for example), few of them, and measure the actual power consumption of modern computers on your all 75 machines. Then submit the data to your management, and compare with your established power limits, accounting for cost of batteries, and don't forget the negative environmental impact of batteries disposal. I am sure the simple AC fans will win hands down.

Comment: Thank you Ali for a great explanation. I did mean 5v usb and not 12V. Your suggestions are well taken. What we need at the office level for fans is not much more than a toy otherwise papers would be blowing around. I have a $10 USB fan that is very adequate. We are getting new computers rolled out to the group over the next 3 weeks so I will keep trying to make a case. Although your points are all taken. Thanks again!!